# Inventing a simple argument parser in c

Tags: c

I know that I can just use getopt or other library for this stuff, but I'm reinventing the wheel. I don't want to just sit here and think that "get opt just automagically parse the option for you".

so here is what I created:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct option_properties
{
    char *arglong;
    int tag;
};


int main(int argc, char **argv){

    struct option_properties options[] =
    {
        {"--input",  0},
        {"--output", 1},
        {"NULL", 2}
    };

    int i;
    int flag;
    int k = 1;
    for (; k < argc; k++){ //part 0
        printf("%d\n", k);
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){ // part 1
        if (!strcmp(argv[k], options[i].arglong)){ // part 2
                switch (options[i].tag) //part 3
                    {
                    case 0:
                        printf("argument input: %s\n", argv[k+1]);
                        break;
                    case 1:

                        printf("argument output: %s\n", argv[k+1]);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;

                    }
                break;              
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

`struct option_properties` is a structure that contain the tag of a certain option.

`struct option_properties options[]` contains the usable options and what its number tag. This number tag can later be use for the `for` ladder.

part 0: starts to count from `k` to `argc`.

part 1: we will scan the `struct option_properties option[]`. note: it's size is 3.

part 2: compares if an option (`argv[k]`) exists in `options[i].arglong`

part 3: if exists, get its number tag and execute the number it's similar to.

While this can parse option, It can not detect an invalid option (or an option not found in options[]).

My brain isn't fit for solving how can it detect an invalid option. If you could, please help.

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent the wheel just for fun/learning, or is there any functionality in getopt that you are missing?

Comment: @klutt getopt is good, I just want to learn how to create a arg parser. By doing it, I know what it does and I can tweak it for my preferences.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't detect an invalid option? Try gdb, it's fairly a small code to debug and u can do it in minutes.

Comment: I can't see a `printf` for an invalid option!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some suggestions:

- Use `sizeof(options) / sizeof(struct option_properties)` instead of `3`.
- Using `sizeof()`, you could do without `{"NULL", 2}`.
- Move `int k = 1` inside `for()`: `for (int k = 1; k < argc; k++)`.
- I strongly advise you to stop using TAB characters to indent your code. Change your editor settings to TAB-inserts-4-spaces.

Then to check if an option is invalid, you could add a `int found = 0` variable which you set to `1` if `!strcmp(argv[k], options[i].arglong)` is true. And you check `found` after the `for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Before your `for` loop over `options`, set a boolean variabele `found` to `FALSE`. When you find a match, set it to `TRUE`.

After the loop, check the value of `found`. If it is `FALSE` print some kind of error message.

Comment: Don't it would also think that an arg followed by the option (ex --input hello. hello is the arg) is also an invalid option?

Comment: @harieamjari You have to process option arguments inside the loop, probably in your `switch` statement. If an option has an argument, you need to manually increase `k`.

Answer (score 0):

The question should rather be, what a valid option is. People coming from Windows often have a completely different expectation how parameters look like, e.g. starting with a slash instead a minus. What is valid is therefore completely implementation dependant and to be considered a usability feature, if you solve it a common way.

I think, that you have already in your program the code path for invalid options. It is the `default:` case in your switch statement. But what I do not like about your code is, that you are using [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)), which you defined in 
`struct option_properties`. The disadvantage is, that you have to remember the mapping between option and a number, which is error prone, especially with more options. You could improve that by using an `enum` instead to have meaningful names for your `case`'s.

But I would consider a flat solution even simpler. I have written such and it iterates over a char pointer. Look how tidy that is:

```
// compile: cc -Wall -g -o main main.c 
// exec: ./main -b -a --testC noParA -e -d -\| --test\| noParB 

#include <string.h> // used to parse long options
#include <stdio.h>  // contains puts
#include <stdlib.h> // contains EXIT_SUCCESS    

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    for(int i=0; i<argc; i++) {
        const char * arg = argv[i];
        if (*arg == '-') { // is the first char a minus '-')?
          while (*arg++ != '\0') {
              if (*arg == '-') { // another '-', long option?
                arg++; // next char
                if(strcmp(arg, "testA") == 0) puts("option --testA provided");
                if(strcmp(arg, "testB") == 0) puts("option --testB provided");
                if(strcmp(arg, "testC") == 0) puts("option --testC provided");
                if(strcmp(arg, "testD") == 0) puts("option --testD provided");
                if(strcmp(arg, "testE") == 0) puts("option --testE provided");
                if(strcmp(arg, "test|") == 0) puts("option --test| provided");
              } else {
                switch(*arg) {
                    case 'a': puts("option a selected"); break;
                    case 'b': puts("option b selected"); break;
                    case 'c': puts("option c selected"); break;
                    case 'd': puts("option d selected"); break;
                    case 'e': puts("option e selected"); break;
                    case '|': puts("option | selected"); break;
                }
              }
          }
        } else {
            printf("Argument without a minus: %s\n", arg); // maybe invalid?
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I have solve it myself:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct option_properties
{
    char *arglong;
    int tag;
};


int main(int argc, char **argv){

    struct option_properties options[] =
    {
        {"--input",  0},
        {"--output", 1},
        {"NULL", 2}
    };

    enum {

        input = 0,
        output = 1
    };
    printf("%d\n", argc);

    int i;
    int flag;
    int k = 1;
    for (; k < argc; ){
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            if (!strcmp(argv[k], options[i].arglong)){
                switch (options[i].tag)
                    {
                    case input:
                        printf("argument input: %s\n", argv[k+1]);
                        break;
                    case output:

                        printf("argument output: %s\n", argv[k+1]);
                        break;
                    default:
                        printf("unk %s\n", argv[k]);
                        exit(1);
                    }
                    printf("1\n");
                    k += 2;
                break;  
            }
            else {
                if (i == 2) {
                    printf("Ooooops: %s %d", argv[k], k);
                    exit(1);
                }
            }            

        }       
    }
}
```

I just used `k` to skip over some arguments so that It wouldn't count as invalid options.

Comment: You could further improve this code by reordering the enum and struct and then also use the enum values ``input`` and ``output`` within the struct. That would completely eliminate magic numbers. Additionally many coding style standards would write enum values in upper case letters and with a prefix, e.g. https://users.ece.cmu.edu/~eno/coding/CCodingStandard.html#enames